# Dynamic detection of content

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have html that generates `<div>` codes like this

```
<div>
     <div>
       <div id ="title"> This is my Title</div>
     </div>
     <div id ="description"> This is Description</div>
</div>
```

and I need to get the content of those div sometimes the div id change or sometimes give no  id. My question is how can I get the value or the content of that div if the div's id changes every time I load the page or is there any way or idea on how can I achieve it and I need to know if that div contains description or title? I think it's hard to implement.

Comment: It is indeed hard to implement. In fact, it's impossible, unless the elements you're looking for have another distinctive characteristic (for instance, always have the same ancestor chain). Is that the case?

Comment: well it has some element but the element change too the only constant element is the div i think i need to make a some kind of reader for every div to know what kind of content it will have

Comment: Does the structure change too? Or can you rely on the fact, that the `title` element will always be the 3rd div?

Comment: In which way can you control those elements? If you have only title and description and you can have put a class on those elements which you know won't change, you have your elements. About which one is which, a simple solution is to check for text length. Usually the title is shorter than description.

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus yes the structure changes and i don't have the control over it

Comment: @ep0 well it has location too i just give the code as an example. some of the location and description has almost same in length

Comment: What's AJAX being used for? If you are getting the content of the DIV via an AJAX call you could parse the returned data before putting it into the document.

Comment: So in order to help you, you should post some examples of how exactly the strctures may look like in different scenarios. Maybe the idea of ep0 is an option? You also could try to stip all divs without a text node and use the first+second one, if the order is always the same

Comment: @Adrian well if i can get the content of the div detect if it's title description etc.. i will put the content to an XML file

Comment: Could you post an excerpt from the code that generates the html ?

Answer (score 0):

If you could add an id or a class to the parent element of those divs.

```
<div id='wrapper'>
     <div>
       <div id ="title"> This is my Title</div>
     </div>
     <div id ="description"> This is Description</div>
</div>
```

You could:

```
var title_html = $('.wrapper').find('div#title').html();
var desc_html = $('.wrapper').find('div#description').html();
```

And the you may check the values of those variables.

In case the id is completely random but the structure is static you could:

```
var contents_one = $('wrapper').children().get(0).children().get(0).html();
var contents_two = $('wrapper').children().get(1).html();
```

Comment: i don't have control of the div i just get whatever div is being created or generated

Comment: You have anything static - specific in your page in order to distinguish your target?

Comment: well i can only read div but cannot change the structure or change the element of it the only way i can detect if the div is title or description is through it's content